# Java Byte[] to int (Big Endian) using << Weirdness

Tags: java, int, byte, endianness

Suppose we have the following byte[4]:

44 a4 8a c6

So in what's wrong with the following code:

```
public static int asIntBigEndian(byte[] raw, int offset){
int result = 0;
for(int i=offset; i<offset+4; ++i){
    result = (result << 4) | raw[i]; 
}
return result;
}
```

The result of calling asIntBigEndian(raw, 0) is:

ff ff ff e6

What I have noticed is that if I were to read the first byte and print it out, I get:

44

I would get the same result if I were to do this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(raw[0] << 24));
```

0x44000000

So If I were to continue the logic ...

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString( (raw[0] << 24)|(raw[1] << 16) );
```

0xffa40000

Basically the first byte turned into 0xff while the 2nd byte 0xa4 has been "xor" onto the right position. Why is this happening?

Comment: Aren't numbers signed in Java?

Comment: Those are not valid byte values. Please give us a minimal working example.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Yes, Java is signed ... but it shouldn't matter if I were to print it out in Hex right?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What do you mean they are not valid byte values? 0x44a48ac6 = 1151634118.

Comment: It's not 0xA4, it's -0x5C. What is -0x5C << 16? It's -0x5C0000. What is 0x44000000 | -0x5C0000?

Comment: What values does your `byte[]` argument contain?

Comment: Suppose we have the following byte[4]:
44 a4 8a c6. So shifting the 2nd index 16 bits up, should get 00a40000 and or with previously 1st index 24 bits up, should get 44000000 | 00a40000 = 44a40000

Comment: @ChaosXDemon 0xA4 is not a valid `byte` value. `byte`s in Java have a range from -128 to 127 (-0x80 to 0x7F)

Comment: @immibis indeed! I forgot about this! So I have to convert the byte to short and then convert to int?

Comment: However ... if I were to print out String.format("%02x", raw[0]) for each byte, i get 44 a4 8a c6. Does that mean it is valid?

Comment: Do `Arrays.toString(raw)` and show us that.

Comment: Hex printing doesn't account for the signs. It would be equally valid to think of 0xA4 being a byte, except that it doesn't work that way in mathematical operations (it works as -0x5C).

Comment: I get [68, -92, -118, -58] which indicates the 2nd byte is not valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`byte`s in Java have a range from -128 (-0x80) to 127 (0x7F). 164 (0xA4) is not a valid value, but "A4" is what you get by printing -92 (-0x5C) as if it was unsigned.

Converting -0x5C to an `int` also gives -0x0000005C. -0x0000005C, printed as unsigned, is 0xFFFFFFA4.

Another, possibly simpler, way to think about it is to think of all values as unsigned, but treat the conversion as a sign extension - where the top bit gets copied into all the new bits. If you think of it this way, 0xA4 is a valid byte and (int)0xA4 is 0xFFFFFFA4. Same result, easier thought process, but it's a less correct way to think about numbers in Java (not that it makes a difference).

`0xFFFFFFA4 << 16` gives `0xFFA40000` and `0x44000000 | 0xFFA40000` gives `0xFFA40000` - which is how you got that result.

The fix is simple - instead of `raw[i]`, use `((int)raw[i] & 0xFF)`, or just `(raw[i] & 0xFF)` as the conversion to `int` is implicit.

Also, unrelated to that problem, `(result << 4)` should be `(result << 8)`. Otherwise you're calculating `0x44000 | 0xA400 | 0x8A0 | 0xC6` instead of `0x44000000 | 0xA40000 | 0x8A00 | 0xC6`.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, do

```
public static int asIntBigEndian(byte[] raw, int offset){
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(raw, offset, 4);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    return buffer.getInt();
}
```

There's overhead, but it's *so* easy.

For that matter, in your calling code, you might be better served by a ByteBuffer.